# Dúvida com Rotas e Controllers Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

Sou iniciante em Laravel e estou tendo um problema com rotas e controllers. Criei um formulário com a seguinte action:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MatriculasController@formulario' }}
```

Criei uma rota para esta action:

```
Route::post('formulario', 'MatriculasController@formulario');
```

O método formulario do MatriculaController faz algumas operações com os dados recebidos do formulário e deveria retornar uma View:

```
    //função que recebe e manipula os dados do formulario
public function formulario(){
    //recebe os dados do formulario
    $ra=$_POST['ra'];
    $aluno=$_POST['nome'];
    $nasc=$_POST['nascimento'];
    $responsavel=$_POST['responsavel'];
    $cpf=$_POST['cpfResponsavel'];  

    //verifica se o RA foi fornecido
    if (strlen($ra>0)){
        $siga = new Siga();
        $consultaRA=$siga->conecta("select NOM_PESSOA from supervisor.PESSOA where COD_PESSOA='$ra'");
        $resultado=mssql_fetch_array($consultaRA);
        $nome=utf8_encode($resultado['NOM_PESSOA']);
        return View::make('confirmaIdentidade');
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

A View confirmaIdentidade:

```
@extends('templates.templateVeterano')

@section('conteudo')

teste

@stop()
```

O problema é que não está retornando essa view e eu não entendo o motivo. Está retornando uma página em branco com a url /formulario.

Alguém sabe o que posso estar fazendo errado?

Comment: Amanda Lima, já aconteceu muito comigo. Para poder te ajudar, você vai ter que postar parte do seu controller. Pelo menos os métodos envolvidos

Comment: Pode ser muitas coisas: Você está usando uma section que não existe na view pai. Você está acessando um método que não retorna nada.

Comment: Vou editar e postar todo o código

Comment: +1 Porque eu amo Laravel!

Comment: Se eu fosse advinho, teria acertado de prima, hein!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amanda, pelo visto o que faz retornar a página em branco no seu código é o `View::make` que está dentro do `if`.

Se não atender a condição, como ela não é retornada, então seu código retornará uma página em branco.

Para verificar se essa afirmação está correta, experimente fazer isso depois do `if` do `$ra`.

```
return 'Alguma coisa errada';
```

Se isso aparecer, então o motivo alegado acima está correto.

O que pode ser feito - é o que eu faria - é colocar o `return View::make` fora de qualquer condição `if`. Se houver necessidade de mandar uma mensagem de erro, você pode fazer assim:

```
if ($erro) {
     // Como a requisição é post, volta para mesma página
     // com uma mensagem flash na sessão
     return Redirect::back()->with('mensagem', 'Mensagem de erro');
}

return View::make('x');
```

Na view:

```
@if(Session::has('mensagem'))
   {{ Session::get('mensagem') }}
@endif
```

Outro problema que pode ocasionar a página em branco no `Laravel 4` é a incompatibilidade de nome das sessões.

Por exemplo:

```
#view_pai
@yield('content')


 #view_filho
   @extend('view_pai')
   @section('content_')
   {{-- Errei o nome de propósito pra demonstrar --}}
   <div>Alguma coisa</div>
   @stop
```

Se você fizer `View::make('view_filho')`, nada será retornado, já que você não definiu a `section` com o valor correto.

Comment: Coloquei o return como você sugeriu e retornou "Alguma coisa errada". Independente se o return está dentro ou fora do if está funcionando quando mando retornar uma string. Mas não retorna a View nem dentro e nem fora do if :(

Comment: E estou cuidando para que o if sempre seja satisfeito

Comment: @AmandaLima, então verifique se no seu "templateVeterano" existe a `@yield('conteudo')`

Comment: Esse era exatamente o problema! A yield no template era `@yield('content')`

Comment: Sabia, só podia ser uma coisa ou outra. Vou adicionar na resposta.